# Repartition Hard Drive

Tags: 14.04

I installed Zorin os8 with ubuntu 14.04.  This automatically partitioned the hard drive, one partition for each os.  I have since deleted the zorin install, and want to get back the space it took on the hard drive for the ubuntu install.  Can I do this by reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo parted -l` and append the results to your question

Answer (score 2):

No reinstall needed you can use Gparted and extend your ubuntu partition. Create a live Ubuntu usb boot from it and use Gparted to extend your Ubuntu partition. (you cannot resize with Gparted while running Ubuntu so use Ubuntu live usb/cd).

i forgot to mention you should use "Try Ubuntu without installing" as @user68186 said

Comment: You have to use the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option to get to gparted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by reinstalling ubuntu. However, there are easier ways. If you do not want to reinstall ubuntu, I would recommend using Gparted partition editor. To do this, you will have to create an ubuntu live usb disk or cd. If you don't already have a .iso of ubuntu, you can download it from ubuntu.com. Once you have downloaded the iso, you can either open startup disk creator from your dashboard and create a usb disk, or burn it to a cd and boot from that. After you have booted from the cd or usb disk (by choosing try ubuntu without installing), open Gparted and you should be able to move the start of your ubuntu os partition to the beginning of the disk, after deleting the zorin os8 partition.

Note: be very careful when doing this, as you will lose your install if you accidentally delete the wrong partition.

P.S. Gparted may require you to unmount the volumes you are working on before editing them. To do this from Gparted, just right click and select "unmount". Also remember that nothing is actually done until you hit the apply button.

Make sure you do not move your /boot partition, (if you have one) and if your computer will not boot afterwards, you may need to reinstall GRUB. The easiest way to do this is by following the method here: http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: A default Ubuntu installation does not have boot partition. You cannot unmount / while Ubuntu is running from that partition. You have to use a live USB/DVD to do it.

Comment: user68186 is correct, sorry about that, I had a bit of a senior moment there. I've updated my post to reflect that. My apologies.